# React - Triggering getter methods of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Google has a lot on this much discussed subject, yet, i can't find a clear solution to my problem (a probably common one).

I have a parent component and a child component (see drawing below), where the child component produces values to be stored somewhere, and the parent has a button triggering the store operation:

[image]

In such a case, the parent does not wish to set or modify any of the child props or state, but rather get some value from it.

To me it seems like the best approach for that is to use `ref` and call a child component method to get the values; but i'm trying very much to avoid using ref as any react documentation suggests.

Is this a use case where i'm better off using refs, or am i missing a better approach? What are the disadvantages of using refs in such a case?

Comment: Expose child prop method to parent.

Comment: just use a callback, define a method `storeInput` or something on your parent, and pass it as a prop to the child. Then call that method with the data from the child as an argument

Comment: what might be useful is redux&react solution (https://redux.js.org/). which is also a popular combination. The basic idea of it is all states will be store in the same place and read-only, changes can only be made with pure functions.  Here is an example provided by official https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't see any issues by using `refs`. It's actually appropriate for your case since it's a on-demand request. But you can use the mechanism of [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) which is described in the docs.

Essentially you would use a callback mechanism. Every time the child component gets an input you will call `onChangeInput(input)` which is implement in the parent component. There you can store it somewhere and use it.

---

For example, a child component that produces random numbers on a button click, and a parent that does something with the latest produces value from the child:

```
class Parent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.childData = null;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child onChange={(data) => this.childData = data}/>
                <button onClick={() => console.log("data to be consumed", this.childData)}>Consume Data</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const Child = (props) => (
    <button onClick={() => props.onChange(Math.random())}>Produce Data</button>
);
```

Comment: So just to clarify, since I've chosen this answer eventually, the idea is to always pass the latest child data to the parent, the parent should always keep this data and then use it when triggered. I might add an example so it'd be clearer for future readers. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

- Set initial state in parent for what you want to grab from the child. In this case temp will store data from child.
- Create a getter function in Parent component and that function will take a parameter. This parameter is the data you are trying to pass to the parent.
- Now you need something to trigger the getter function so for demonstration purposes I just added a button and when it is clicked it will pass the data from child to parent and it will be rendered in the parent.
- Now when the button is clicked it will render Hello which is what is stored inside of the state of child.

  ```
  class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props)
    this.state = {
     temp:'',
    }
   }

   getFromChild = (data) => {
    this.setState({ temp:data })
   }
   render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <div> THIS IS FROM CHILD: {this.state.temp} </div>
       <Child getFromChild={this.getFromChild}/>
      </div>
    )
   }
  }

  class Child extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props)
    this.state = {
     data:'hello',
    }
   }
   render() {
    return( 
     <button onClick={() => this.props.getFromChild(this.state.data)}> view data </button>
    )
   }  
  }
  ```

PART 2

- Since the button is in the parent we need a way to let the child know
  whether or not to pass the data when that button is clicked that is
  why we declare `pass` in state.
- Once the button is clicked `pass` is now true.
- Inside the Child component `this.props.getFromChild(this.state.data)` will be called.

  ```
   class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        temp: "",
        pass: false
      };
    }

    getFromChild = data => {
      this.setState({ temp: data });
    };
    passData = () => {
      this.setState({ pass: true });
    };
    render() {
      console.log(this.state.pass);
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            {" "}
            THIS IS PARENT COMPONENTS STATE:{" "}
            {!this.state.temp && <div> NOTHING YET </div>}
            {this.state.temp}{" "}
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => this.passData()}> Pass the data </button>
          <Child
            temp={this.state.temp}
            pass={this.state.pass}
            getFromChild={this.getFromChild}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

    class Child extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: "hello"
      };
    }
    render() {
      if (this.props.pass & (this.props.temp !== this.state.data)) {
        this.props.getFromChild(this.state.data);
      }
      return (
        <div>
          {" "}
          This is the child component <br /> state::: data: {this.state.data}{" "}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
  ```

  [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ykr2r2z0jz)

Comment: This addresses the case where the child holds the button that triggers the operation. In my case the parent component has the button. Any solution for that?

Comment: I've looked at it! Thanks for helping. It solves the issue but the other answer seems much simpler for my use case so I've decided to go with it. Thanks for the help.